# Repeat list elements based on values in another list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
nums = [2, 3, 5]
mylist = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
```

What I am trying to achieve is repeat each element in `mylist` as many times as the corresponding values in `nums`. Expected output is:

```
["aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "ccc", "ccc", "ccc", "ccc", "ccc"]
```

Comment: Use `zip()` to loop over the two lists in parallel. Then use a nested loop to append the string to the result list the specified number of times.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: @Barmar You cannot know that this is a homework problem.  This particular challenge arises periodically in real world code.  Also, the range of solutions is not obvious even for many experienced coders.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger Maybe, but I feel comfortable in my guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us do `repeat`

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series(mylist).repeat(nums).tolist()
Out[554]: ['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc']
```

Or try `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
np.repeat(mylist,nums)
Out[556]: 
array(['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc',
       'ccc'], dtype='<U3')
```

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You cannot know for sure whether this is a homework problem.  This particular situation arises in real world code.  Also, even experienced coders won't find the the range of solution options to be obvious.

Comment: I hesitated to make the callout when I saw that you had also answered the question, but. While I don't know it's a homework question, I do know that no attempt to answer the question has been shown, and that all of the various solutions shown are a matter of combining elementary techniques. It doesn't make an appropriate question for Stack Overflow because it is not clear why OP was unable to write the code already.

Answer (score 8):

Several solutions come to mind.

### High level code with Counter

The easiest way is to use the [elements()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.elements) method for [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> nums = [2, 3, 5]
>>> mylist = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
>>> list(Counter(dict(zip(mylist, nums))).elements())
['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc']
```

### Functional C-speed code with itertools

Or you can use the [itertools module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) directly:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, repeat
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, mylist, nums)))
['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc']
```

### Native language syntax (no libraries)

To do this without libraries, a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) would suffice:

```
>>> [elem for n, elem in zip(nums, mylist) for i in range(n)]
['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc']
```

Comment: Please do not answer homework questions like this. They are supposed to be closed, as OP has not demonstrated any attempt to solve the problem and has not even *asked an actual question*.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate both the lists in parallel using `zip`, then get the required value list with list multiplication by `n`:

```py
nums = [2, 3, 5]
mylist = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
out = []
for v,n in zip(mylist, nums):
    out.extend([v]*n)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
>>> out
['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc']
```

Comment: Please do not answer homework questions like this. They are supposed to be closed, as OP has not demonstrated any attempt to solve the problem and has not even *asked an actual question*.

Comment: That said, I do particularly like this approach. While I generally try to write in a functional rather than procedural style for simple cases, Python's sequence multiplication is an elegant trick, and that trick is useful here and not (AFAICT) for any of the usual functional idioms.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
nums = [2, 3, 5]
mylist = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]

out = [s for n, s in zip(nums, mylist) for _ in range(n)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc']
```

Comment: Please do not answer homework questions like this. They are supposed to be closed, as OP has not demonstrated any attempt to solve the problem and has not even *asked an actual question*.